# How to define jade as a global variable in node.js Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, include, pug

Right now the following routing function works:

```
exports.summary = function(req, res, next) { 
  var jade = require('jade');
  res.render('myView', {
     main: jade.renderFile('./views/summary.jade')
  });
};
```

As you can see, the variable 'jade' is defined locally everytime the routing function is triggered. This can be a concern to performance. Whenever I tried to define jade globally, I received an error message saying jade is not defined.

Is there a way for me to define 'jade' globally?

Comment: why can't you define it at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s    global.jade = require('jade');

Read more about global [here](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

But for your case it's better just to define jade in the module level:

```
var jade = require('jade');
exports.summary = function(req, res, next) { 
  res.render('myView', {
     main: jade.renderFile('./views/summary.jade')
  });
};
```

This should work.